# Payment method declined but user is still subscribed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I have a website built on the PHP Laravel Framework. I use Stripe to process recurring subscription fees for the service via Laravel Cashier. This is the code for the `SubscriptionController.php`:

```
class SubscriptionController extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function payment()
    {
        $availablePlans =[
           'monthly-4_99' => "Monthly",
           'yearly' => "Yearly"
        ];

        $data = [
            'intent' => auth()->user()->createSetupIntent(),
            'plans'=> $availablePlans
        ];

        return view('user.subscribe')->with($data);
    }

    public function subscribe(Request $request)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $paymentMethod = $request->payment_method;
        $planId = $request->plan;
        $coupon = $request->coupon;

        if ($coupon == 'Free60') {
            $user->newSubscription('plan', $planId)->trialDays(60)->create($paymentMethod);
        } else if ($coupon == '1YrEA') {
            $planId = 'monthly-4_99';
            $user->newSubscription('plan', 'monthly-4_99')->trialDays(365)->create($paymentMethod);
        } else if ($coupon == 'LAT-44') {
            $planId = 'monthly-4_99';
            $user->newSubscription('plan', 'monthly-4_99')->withCoupon($coupon)->create($paymentMethod);
        } else {
            $user->newSubscription('plan', $planId)->create($paymentMethod);
        }

        if ($planId == 'monthly-4_99') {
            return response([
                'success_url'=> redirect()->intended('memorials')->with('success', 'You are now subscribed to a monthly plan.')->getTargetUrl()
            ]);
        } else if ($planId == 'yearly') {
            $user = auth()->user();
            User::find($user->id)->update(['free_qrplaque' => 'yes']);

            return response([
                'success_url'=> redirect()->intended('memorials')->with('success', 'You are now subscribed to a ' . $planId . ' plan.')->getTargetUrl()
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

This works as it should, but there is one problem I just discovered. When a user's payment information is no longer valid, the user remains subscribed and has access to all premium features of the service. When I try to cancel the subscription by clicking the "Unsubscribe" button, the website gives me a `500 Server Error`. Here is the code for canceling a subscription:

```
public function cancel()
    {
        $user = auth()->user();

        $user->subscription('plan')->cancel();

        return redirect()->back()->with("success", "Your subscription has been canceled.");
    }
```

When the user logs in and views the dashboard, I have some code that checks if they are subscribed. If they are not, I process the changes to reflect a free user's capabilities (not being able to publish memorials). Here is the code:

```
public function index()
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    if (!$user->subscribed('plan') && $user->memorials->count() > 0) {
        foreach ($user->memorials as $memorial) {
            $memorial->update(['status' => 'unpublished']);
        }
    }

    return view('memorials');
}
```

I'm assuming this code is not targeting the correct variable to check if the user is still subscribed, or if I need to add additional code for when a user's payment method is declined to make the necessary changes in the database to reflect being unsubscribed.

If anyone can help me fix this issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What website are you getting the `500 Server Error` on? If you're seeing that after trying to cancel the Subscription through Stripe's Dashboard you probably want to talk to their support team (https://support.stripe.com/contact) but if this is from your own website can you share your code for cancelling the subscription?

Comment: I'm getting the Server Error on my website, not on Stripe. In Stripe, it recognizes the payment method has failed. I added the code for canceling the subscription in my question above.

Comment: It's likely the issue is in `$user->subscription('plan')->cancel();` it's not clear what this code actually does. In general please try to remove any parts of the code that are not relevant to the actual issue

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message. For Laravel, check in `storage/logs`.

Comment: That code is relevant to the issue, as it relies on finding the users `subscription('plan')` to cancel it. If the `subscription('plan')` is null, then I need to add some code to check that part of the database and update the user's subscription status as soon as a payment fails on Stripe's end.

Comment: I checked the `storage/logs` and it shows this error:  `production.ERROR: A canceled subscription can only update its cancellation_details. {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Stripe\\Exception\\InvalidRequestException(code: 0): A canceled subscription can only update its cancellation_details.`

Comment: It sounds like the subscription is already cancelled on Stripe's end, so maybe you just need to update your data locally?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to try to do. I guess didn't account for this issue when I was coding this part of my website. It is canceled on Stipes end and says "Payment Failed". I'd like to figure out what I need to add to have the website automatically update the user's subscription status when it sees a payment has been declined. The problem here is I don't know how to recreate this issue locally, so I am trying to diagnose this in a production environment....

Comment: Have you made sure that you have a Stripe Webhook setup to listen for when Subscriptions are cancelled by Stripe (see https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/billing#handling-stripe-webhooks)?